# Rails 4 "no implicit conversion of Symbol into String" only in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I am receiving an error in production only that says:

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into String):
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:15:in `create'
```

Here is the relevant code from the products_controller.rb file (note the line in question is line 2 below)

```
def create
  @product = @category.products.build(product_params)
  if @product.save
    flash[:success] = "Product successfully created"
    redirect_to [@category, @product]
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Product not created"
    render 'new'
  end
end

private

  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :url, :category_id, :picture, :price, :social_image)
  end
```

This code currently works fine in development and test environments and was previously working in production (will explain changes since last working production version below). I have used a diff tool to confirm that the Gemfile.lock is identical between local and production machines to eliminate that aspect also.

**Note:** I previously had file uploads working using the Paperclip gem as seen in the :picture param, however I recently included a second file upload for this model (:social_image) and also switched the upload method to Amazon S3 via the aws-sdk gem rather than just to the production server. Also, I have confirmed that all relevant settings between development.rb and production.rb are correct.

The params for the request can be found below:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"yJJ1HwLZz9oDmsfUfN87DATCe+HC9IBhYVBddRvm4=",
 "product"=>{"name"=>"Heineken Style USB Flash Drive",
 "description"=>"Sample Description.",
 "url"=>"http://www.amazon.com/",
 "category_id"=>"1",
 "price"=>"7.99",
 "picture"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000004986260 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20131013-3068-fyjvy2>,
 @original_filename="heineken-usb-drive-stock.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"product[picture]\"; filename=\"heineken-usb-drive-stock.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">,
 "social_image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000049861c0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20131013-3068-1glzf9p>,
 @original_filename="heineken-usb-drive.png",
 @content_type="image/png",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"product[social_image]\"; filename=\"heineken-usb-drive.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">},
 "commit"=>"Create Product",
 "category_id"=>"geeky"}
```

I have included a stack track below as well for everyones reference:

```
paperclip (3.5.1) lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb:141:in `gsub'
paperclip (3.5.1) lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb:141:in `block in extended'
paperclip (3.5.1) lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb:117:in `instance_eval'
paperclip (3.5.1) lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb:117:in `extended'
paperclip (3.5.1) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:390:in `extend'
paperclip (3.5.1) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:390:in `initialize_storage'
paperclip (3.5.1) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:85:in `initialize'
paperclip (3.5.1) lib/paperclip/has_attached_file.rb:46:in `new'
paperclip (3.5.1) lib/paperclip/has_attached_file.rb:46:in `block in define_instance_getter'
paperclip (3.5.1) lib/paperclip/has_attached_file.rb:65:in `block in define_setter'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:42:in `public_send'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:42:in `_assign_attribute'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:29:in `block in assign_attributes'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:23:in `each'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:23:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/core.rb:192:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:27:in `new'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:27:in `new'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:189:in `build_association'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:242:in `build_record'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:114:in `build'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:229:in `build'
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:16:in `create'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:443:in `_run__3726568038748606890__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__1565355437262191815__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
/home/application/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.16/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:77:in `process_request'
/home/application/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.16/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:140:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
/home/application/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.16/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:108:in `main_loop'
/home/application/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.16/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:441:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
```

Finally the full codebase is available at: https://github.com/mhoad/there-goes-my-paycheck/tree/deployment should anyone want to check out any other files.

Any help would this would be majorly appreciated! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your production.rb file, paperclip is configured with `:url => :s3_domain_url`, while in dev it's `:url => ':s3_domain_url'` (note the quotation marks). Seems like you could move the whole config.paperclip_defaults to application.rb as well, so you're guaranteed the same settings even when something changes.

Thanks for posting a link to the repo, by the way - it's much easier to spot these things when you can see the whole app.

Comment: Not a problem I thought it was the least I could do for anyone who would take the time to help me. Also thanks a lot for not just taking my word for it when I said I had already checked those files to be correct. I have been stuck on this for hours and I was just far too deep into it to notice something so small.